# Generate a sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to enter a value/sequence to MySQL field automatically. Here is my sequence:

```
2342/ABC/2013/08/01
```

The last one is my sequence like `01`, `02`, `03`, and so on.

The rule is when a month changes like in above month is 08 when it is `09` i want to start sequence again from `01`, `02` and so on.

I have a table `table1(Id,User_name,Sq_Number)`

I will just use this

```
Insert into table1('User_name') values('BILL')
```

It will insert sequence automatically

Comment: There is no simple way to do this, but you can probably pull off something similar using stored procedures. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html -- don't ask me how though, I'm not really familiar with them.

Comment: Whereas, in contrast with many developers, I believe that placing as much as the business logic on the database layer is generally a good idea, in this particular case you are better off calculating the sequence value in your PHP code.

Comment: What does **2342** mean? What does **ABC** mean?

Comment: This is just pattern..do not confuse it..these will be canstant...

Comment: The best way to generate this type of sequence is to write a function/procedure which retrieve last insert value and generate next value.

Comment: So to clarify: imagine `table1` is empty. If I ran your example `INSERT` statement today (2013-08-20), what would the contents of the table look like?

Comment: table will be like this "1 BILL 2342/ABC/2013/08/01"

Answer (score 0):

Use before insert trigger, something like that (below I create sequence from current date), just add your logic (it's not clear for me).

```
CREATE trigger insert_processor
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set new.Sq_Number = CONCAT('2342','/','ABC','/', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y/%m/%d'));

END$$
```

If you need unique sequence it's good practice to create table for that and use select in trigger.